# resizing mechanism covered by content element

Tags: css, cross-browser, resize

The resizing mechanism is covered by `#inner` element on Chrome, but shown on Firefox.

Here is sample codes:

```html
<div id="outer" style="width:200px; height: 30px; background: lightgreen; overflow: hidden; resize: both; position: relative;">
  <div id="inner" style="position: absolute; right: 0; width: 100px; height: 100%; background: lightblue;"></div>
</div>
```

Result:

Chrome:

[image: Render result in Google Chrome; Resizing mechanism is covered by #inner element]

Firefox:

[image: Render result in Mozilla Firefox; Resizing mechanism is shown correctly]

First question is: Which behavior is correct one? Or is there specification of what browser SHOULD do?

Second question is: I want all browsers show the resizing mechanism (just like what Firefox does), so that I can resize the `#outer` element. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you try to add `z-index` to ::webkit-resizer ? Not sure if it will work, just a guess

Comment: @disstruct I had tried `::-webkit-resizer { z-index: 1000; position: relative; }
` but it does not work.

Comment: The problem is firefox is misreading. The resizer is on the green layer and so if you make the blue transparent you will see it.

Comment: `will see it` is not what i want, i want change the size of `#outer`

Answer (score 0):

Changed the placement of green and blue so the left side with blue was revealed and showing the resizer.

```html
<div id="outer" style="width:200px; height: 30px; background: lightblue; overflow: hidden; resize: both; position: relative;">
  <div id="inner" style="right: 0; width: 100px; height: 100%; background: lightgreen;"></div>
</div>
```